# Can probabilities be used relatively?

Tags: probability

There is a pokereval library which provides very good probablistic equities for poker hands. e.g.

> As Ks 81% vs 2s 7c
>
> As Ks 79% vs 9c 9h
>
> 9c 9h 60% vs 2s 7c

So that gives heads up equities. What if the all 3 hands were in the same game: would you be able to from the given/known 1on1 equities be able to deduce their winning probability/equity?

e.g.

> as Ks 66%
>
> 9c 9h 21%
>
> 2s 7c 13%

How would I make that calculation? Let me know if you need more information, it's hard for me to phrase this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot infere much from the pairwise probabilities. Let me put a more convenient example (where I invent probabilities):

As Ks 70% vs Ah Qh

Ah Qh 78% vs 9c 9h

As Ks 80% vs 9c 9h

When an ace appears Ah Qh wins 9c 9h, but that's also when AsKs will beat AhQh, so even though Ah Qh fares relatively well in pairwise computations it is possible that it fares worse than 9c 9h when playing all at the same time.

Even more, when we have the 3 pairs there are some cards that could be dealt before (such as As when doing AhQh vs 9c9h) that are now impossible to be dealt because one of the players has it.